# Javascript variable not being seen in HTML

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular app where I am trying to get a javascript variable to show up in HTML. This does work in an older part of my application. However, it will not work in the new part.

Here is the working function (inside a file called `reports.js`):

```
  return db.queryPromise(sql, sqlParams().then(function(results) {
    console.log("Inside queryPromise");
    var data = {
       GrandTotals: {
          Expensed: 0
       }
    };

    results.reduce(function(data,record) {
      var expensed = record['Expensed'];
      data.GrandTotals.Expensed = expensed;
      console.log("Expensed amount:"+data.GrandTotals.Expensed);
      return data;
    }, data);
    return data;
});
```

Here is the working html (inside a file called `_reportFunds.html`):

```
 <tr class="info bold">
   <td colspan="3">Grand Total</td>
   <td class="text-right"><currency value="data.GrandTotals.Expensed" symbol="$"/></td>
 </tr>
```

Here is the non-working function (inside a file called `crud.js`):

```
return db.queryPromise(sql, sqlParams().then(function(results) {
    console.log("Inside queryPromise-crud");
    var pageObject = {
       GrandTotals: {
          Expensed: 0
       }
    };

    results.reduce(function(pageObject,record) {
      var expensed = record['Expensed'];
      pageObject.GrandTotals.Expensed = expensed;
      console.log("Expensed amount-crud:"+pageObject.GrandTotals.Expensed);
      return pageObject;
    }, pageObject);
    return pageObject;
});
```

Here is the non-working html (inside a file called `_trans.html`):

```
<tr class="info bold">
  <td colspan="3">Grand Total</td>
  <td class="text-right"><currency value="pageObject.GrandTotals.Expensed" symbol="$"/></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see... the code is basically the same except for a changed variable name. I can see the console.logs print out the expected information to the server. This leads me to believe that the variables should be able to be accessed since the data is showing up. Could there maybe be something that is killing this crud.js file before it is able to pull the values into the html?
thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is an Angular (uppercase A) related-question?

Comment: `symbol="$"`...

Comment: You are correct, its probably just Javascript. I added Angular since that is what the app uses. Maybe there is a better "Angular-centric" way to do this?

Comment: @Danny Fardy Jhonston Bermúdez - oops... type error on my part since I cant copy/paste from source into here.

Comment: Are you sure your promise resolves? Do you see this "console.log("Inside queryPromise-crud");" in your console?

Comment: are you doing this in a life-cycle hook of any kind? It sounds like some sort of async operation not completing issue but I didn't really disect your code that much tbh...

Comment: @argoo... yes, the console.log statements show up. This is what makes me think I should be able to see these variables.

Comment: @Blair Holmes  These variables are populated from a function call kicked off by the router so it doesnt appear there is any life-cycle hook in there.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I never quite figured out how to get that current code working. But in doing some more research into totaling I found a neat little angular way to handle this and give me my totals.

Here is the html:

```
<td class="text-right">{{getTotalExpense}}</td>
```

Here is the code in the controller:

```
$scope.getTotalExpense = function() {
   var total = 0;
   for(var i=0; i<$scope.displayed.length; i++){
      var product = $scope.displayed[i];
      total += (product.Expensed);
   }

   return '$' + total.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,'$1,')
}
```